# JavaScript regular expression to catch kanji

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I can't get this javascript function to work the way I want...

// matches a String that contains kanji and/or kana character(s)

```
String.prototype.isKanjiKana = function(){
    return !!this.match(/^[\u4E00-\u9FAF|\u3040-\u3096|\u30A1-\u30FA|\uFF66-\uFF9D|\u31F0-\u31FF]+$/);
}
```

it does return TRUE if the string is made of kanji and/or kana characters, FALSE if alphabet or other chars are present.

I would like it to return if at least 1 kanji and/or kana characters are present instead that if all of them are.

thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.prototype.isKanjiKana = function(){
    return !!this.match(/[\u4E00-\u9FAF\u3040-\u3096\u30A1-\u30FA\uFF66-\uFF9D\u31F0-\u31FF]/);
}
```

Don't anchor it to beginning and end of string with `$^` and the `+` is useless in this case.

Comment: thank you! :)  I didn't understood the $ in the end and was all focused on the ^

Comment: doesn't work, this function will also return `true` for the hiragana alphabet

Comment: @vdegenne The ranges of characters were given in the question. The problem of the OP was about anchoring. About how to do what you want, see for example tchrist response.

Comment: @xanatos the range were given in the question because the OP had no idea how to implement it. But the title says it all he needed to a function that returns true if the character is a Kanji. Hiragana and Katakana are not Kanjis. So this answer shouldn't be the accepted one.

Answer (score 9):

The right answer is *not* to hardcode ranges.  Never ever put magic numbers in your code! That is a maintenance nightmare. It is hard to read, hard to write, hard to debug, hard to maintain.  How do you know you got the numbers right? What happens when they add new ones? No, do not use magic numbers.  Please.

The right answer is to use named Unicode scripts, which are a fundemental aspect of every Unicode code point:

```
[\p{Han}\p{Hiragana}\p{Katakana}]
```

That requires the [`XRegExp` plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) for Javascript.

The real problem is that Javascript regexes on their own are **too primitive** to support Unicode properties — and therefore, to support Unicode. Maybe that was once an acceptable compromise 15 years ago, but today it is nothing less than intolerably negligent, as you yourself have discovered.

You will also miss a few `Common` code points specified as kana in the new `Script Extensions` property, but probably no matter. You could just add `\p{Common}`  to the set above.

Comment: So he should trust `XRegExp` (that will do exactly the same, hardcode numbers)? Mmmh... The last release is from 2010-03-24, the last blog entry is 2010-07-05... No, he did the right thing: he created a method with the right name and extended string. Adding the reference to another library IS normally a nightmare ready to raise.

Comment: Sorry, but tchrist is right.  It's true that eventually, somewhere, somehow, there will be database of codepoint numbers, that's inevitable, but unless your specialty is maintaining databases of unicode propertied, you don't want to write your own functions.  Even if you did, the number ranges should at a minimum come from a config file.  Hard-coding in number-ranges will only lead to bugs down the road.  New versions of the unicode databases are released periodically with changes, eratta, etc.  (Also, note that something that works 95%, that you trust is worse than nothing in many cases).

Comment: XRegExp's categories (like `\p{Han}` et al.) compile down to regular JavaScript regexps. Here are the native Javascript regexp for `Han`: `/[\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u3005\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303B\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCC\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9]/`. For `Katakana`: `/[\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FD-\u30FF\u31F0-\u31FF\u32D0-\u32FE\u3300-\u3357\uFF66-\uFF6F\uFF71-\uFF9D]/`. And for `Hiragana`: `/[\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F]/`. Forgive me for not including `\p{Common}` here as it's too big for this commentbox.

Comment: XRegExp’s *Han* category: `XRegExp('\\p{Han}')` is now simplified:
`/[⺀-⺙⺛-⻳⼀-⿕々〇〡-〩〸-〻㐀-䶵一-鿕豈-舘並-龎]/`

Comment: I always revisit this when I need to get XRegExp's raw Han range, but recently, the regexp above fails to compile when pasted into Chrome/Node. So I put the regexp's `source` string through [JavaScript escapes](https://mothereff.in/js-escapes) to get the following: `var hanRegexp = /[\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u3005\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303B\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FEF\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9]/; hanRegexp.test('山')` which will produce the expected results when you copy-paste from here (but you should do this yourself to ensure I'm not lying to you). – Ahmed Fasih 19 mins ago

Comment: See the other answer expanding on this one for a modern solution!

Comment: @aehlke can you look at my comment to Inkling's answer to see if you agree?

Answer (score 5):

Now that Unicode property escapes are part of the ES (2018) spec, the following regex can be used natively if the JS engine supports this feature (expanding on @tchrist's answer):

```
/[\p{Script_Extensions=Han}\p{Script_Extensions=Hiragana}\p{Script_Extensions=Katakana}]/u
```

If you want to exclude punctuation from being matched:

```
/(?!\p{Punctuation})[\p{Script_Extensions=Han}\p{Script_Extensions=Hiragana}\p{Script_Extensions=Katakana}]/u
```

Comment: Note though that XRegExp appears to be a stricter subset than the current JavaScript `Han` script extension. Consider: `'三、四十？！ー'.match(/[\p{Script_Extensions=Han}]/ug)` yields in *four* results, `[ "三", "、", "四", "十" ]`. For some reason, the Japanese comma is included. The XRegExp version yields only three results: `'三、四十?!'.match(/[\u2E80-\u2E99\u2E9B-\u2EF3\u2F00-\u2FD5\u3005\u3007\u3021-\u3029\u3038-\u303B\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FEF\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9]/g)` returns ` "三", "四", "十" ]`. SO. In a nutshell, as always, script is hard, you might run into weird stuff no matter what.

Comment: XRegExp uses the `Script` property, which for `、` [is `Common`](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=3001), meaning the character is used in multiple scripts. This is the same for any other characters that are shared. `Script_Extensions` actually tells you what those scripts are. After taking a look at [the relevant data](http://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/ScriptExtensions.txt), it seems like using `Script` (mimicking XRegExp) instead of `Script_Extensions` would exclude some special Han characters in addition to punctuation. Maybe that's an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: I should also note that you can just exclude punctuation using the `General_Category` property, that's probably the best approach. You can do so using a negative lookahead:    
`/(?!\p{Punctuation})[\p{Script_Extensions=Han}]/ug`    
(You don't actually have to say `General_Category=`, it's implicit)

Answer (score 3):

```
/[\u3000-\u303f]|[\u3040-\u309f]|[\u30a0-\u30ff]|[\uff00-\uffef]|[\u4e00-\u9faf]|[\u3400-\u4dbf]/
```

- Japanese style punctuation: `[\u3000-\u303f]`
- Hiragana: `[\u3040-\u309f]`
- Katakana: `[\u30a0-\u30ff]`
- Roman characters + half-width katakana: `[\uff00-\uffef]`
- Kanji: `[\u4e00-\u9faf]|[\u3400-\u4dbf]`

Answer (score 1):

```
/[\u4E00-\u9FAF|\u3040-\u3096|\u30A1-\u30FA|\uFF66-\uFF9D|\u31F0-\u31FF]/
```

Comment: Excuse me :-( Wrong paste :-( I have rollbacked and I hope everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this? It will return true when it contains at least one Kanji.

```
/[一-龯]/.test(str)
```

Comment: don't do that..

Comment: Why not it is simple and it works

Comment: No it doesn't work. Consider `/[一-龯]/.test('檢')` for example, it returns `true` but in reality this is wrong because `檢` is Chinese, not Japanese (so technically not a Kanji), The Kanji form of the Hanzi `檢` is `検`.
The reason of that is because your regex naively encapsulates all these characters in one go, when in fact a more clean solution would be to choose the ranges more carefully.)

Comment: Thanks:-) It works for my purpose though.